# Wordpress: Fetch Parent Post and his childrens and grandchildrens

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm having 3 different post types (Red, Black, White) and I want to display into a custom page a list with All posts from each post type. Every post has children and grandhildren posts. What i'm trying to acchieve looks like this:

```
[ Red ]

- Post 1 
- Post 2 
- Post 3
  -- Post 4
- Post 5
  -- Post 6
   --- Post 7
- Post 8

[ Black ]

- Post 9 
- Post 10
  -- Post 11
   --- Post 12
- Post 13
  -- Post 14
- Post 15
  -- Post 16
   --- Post 17
- Post 18


[ Black ]

- Post 19 
- Post 20
  -- Post 21
   --- Post 22
- Post 23
  -- Post 24
- Post 25
  -- Post 26
   --- Post 27
- Post 28
```

If and only if it's possible, I would like to display only the children and grand children posts that has an excerpt, leaving the ones who doesn't out of the list.

I really appreciate your help guys, thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use the get_pages function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

If I understand correctly, it should look similar to this:

```
$args = array('post_type'=>'Red');
$pages = get_pages($args); 
foreach ( $pages as $pagg ) {
   if (strip_tags(trim($pagg->post_excerpt))!="") {
       // Your code goes here
   }
}
```